# Stop Thunderbird adding two hyphens above a signature

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-signature

I use Thunderbird for sending e-mails, but its signatures are inconsistent. If you send a new e-mail it will add two hyphens above your signature, but when you send a reply it doesn't. I'd like to set it so it does the same for both, preferably so that it doesn't add them for either. Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/39107/396228

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It Thunderbird go to **Tools >> Options >> Advanced >> Config Editor**

Then search for **mail.identity.default.suppress_signature_separator** and set it to **TRUE** by double-clicking it.

Now, you will no longer get the **--** before the signature.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. That did the trick. Now I can add my own separator instead of having to put up with Thunderbird's.

Comment: a life saver.  why it is a default to add it in and then make the setting so hard to find, I don't know.  not a good user experience.